# Overflow-x scroll only on a parent div with a fixed height and unknown number of children

Tags: html, css

If I have a parent and child div:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="content child">1</div>
</div>
```

The parent div has:

- a fixed height(just over the height of one child)
- a max width(some %)

The content children will be:

- all the same size
- start with one child
- more children will be added, but each child is to be to the right of the last child, therefore, only allow for x scrolling

What CSS is needed on the parent, and each child?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/zKEC7/) with my best attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have all elements in a single line you need to make the child elements display inline-block and disable wrapping of white space on the parent

```
.parent {
    max-width: 50%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKEC7/11/)**

Comment: !Doh   I tried `display:inline-block`, but didn't do `white-space: nowrap`.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.content {
    display: block;
}
```